# Comment form is showing instead of "Add Comment" button in a node in drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-comments

In a Drupal 6 site, I enabled the comment settings for two content types (con 1 & con 2).  After creating a node in con 1 the "Add comment" button is showing at the bottom, but in the case of con 2, after creating the node, it shows a comment form instead of an "Add Comment" button. Both of the content types have the same settings as follows:

> Default comment setting: Read/write.
>
> Default display mode:   Threaded list - expanded
>
> Default display order : Date - newest first
>
> Default comments per page:  50
>
> Comment controls: Do not display
>
> Anonymous commenting:  Anonymous posters may not enter their contact
>   information
>
> Comment subject field: Enabled
>
> Preview comment: Required
>
> Location of comment submission form:  Display on separate page

Comment: What you described here tells that you have different settings for both content types. Check them again, sometimes it help.

Answer (score 0):

Ranjani,

That setting is controlled by the very last comment option when you're editing your content type:

[image]

Like Vlad said above, double check to make sure that really ***is*** the same for both of your content types.  That's precisely what that last option controls: whether the 'add comment' is a form on the node or a link to a separate page where the comment form is displayed.....

Comment: @Vlad Stratula & Boriana.Thanks to both of you.